# whats wrong with synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

What's wrong with code, my threads are not getting synchronized:
I have in below example synchronized print method which thread would call but still the output shows that threads are not synchronized while accessing print method. See output below.

**Main Class**

```
public class ExecutorTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrinterRunnable pr = new PrinterRunnable();
        ExecutorService excutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        //ExecutorService excutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr); 
        excutor.submit(pr);

        excutor.shutdown();

        for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
            System.out.println("In Main Thread : "+i);
    }
}
```

**Thread Class**

```
public class PrinterRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
            //System.out.println("In Thread class" +i);
            Printer p = new Printer();
            p.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

**other class**

```
public class Printer {

    public synchronized void print(int i){
        System.out.println("Entered Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("In thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"count::"+i );
        System.out.println("Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

**Console Output**
(see below thread 13 and 11 are both entered!!!)

```
Entered Thread: 13
Entered Thread: 11
In thread: 11count::0
Exit Thread: 11
Entered Thread: 11
In thread: 11count::1
Exit Thread: 11
In thread: 13count::0
Exit Thread: 13
Entered Thread: 13
In thread: 13count::1
Exit Thread: 13
........
........
........
```

Comment: synchronized only locks the object, not the method, nor all objects. If you give each thread it's own object, this will have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

When the keyword `synchronized` is part of a method signature, as it is in

```
public synchronized void print(int i)
```

then this synchronization refers to the *instance* that this method is called on. You are creating one new `Printer` instance each time that you want to print something.

In order to achieve the desired effect, you have to synchronize on one common object. This could, for example, be achieved like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ExecutorTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrinterRunnable pr = new PrinterRunnable(new Object());
        ExecutorService excutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);
        excutor.submit(pr);

        excutor.shutdown();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println("In Main Thread : " + i);
    }
}

class PrinterRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private final Object monitor;

    PrinterRunnable(Object monitor)
    {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // System.out.println("In Thread class" +i);
            Printer p = new Printer(monitor);
            p.print(i);
        }
    }
}

class Printer
{
    private final Object monitor;

    Printer(Object monitor)
    {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    public void print(int i)
    {
        synchronized (monitor)
        {
            System.out.println("Entered Thread: " + 
                Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.out.println("In thread: " + 
                Thread.currentThread().getId() + " count::" + i);
            System.out.println("Exit Thread: " + 
                Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, this is an overly pragmatic sketch. In your real application, you should carefully think about **which** object you want to synchronize on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help

Answer (score 1):

In this location:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i =0; i<5;i++){
        //System.out.println("In Thread class" +i);
        Printer p = new Printer();
        p.print(i);
    }
}
```

each thread is creating its own Printer for each iteration. Synchronization works by stopping other threads from executing synchronized methods on the same object until one thread is finished with its synchronized method. As per: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` method is per-instance of the object, and as you are creating multiple instances there is no contention.  Depending on your requirements you could change the method to be `static` or synchronize on a class variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help

Answer (score 0):

They synchronized, of course. Every one on it's own monitor, related to it's own Printer object.
Since you are creating 5 different Printer objects, "synchronized" performed on different object, and never lock execution process.

You should create one single object and use it for synchronization.
for example:

```
public class Printer {

    public void print(int i){
        syncrhonized(Printer.class) {
           System.out.println("Entered Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
           System.out.println("In thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"count::"+i );
           System.out.println("Exit Thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

since there is only one Printer.class object, they will be always synchroinzed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help